# Haskell: Explanation of function syntax

Tags: haskell

In this custom made version of the map function, there is an "f" is a few spots. I'm not sure what the f means in the function (I'm a beginner in Haskell). Is it something to do with higher order functions? Can someone explain what f means and then explain what the actual function is doing to create the map functionality?

```
map f [] = []
map f (a:b) = f a:map f b
```

Comment: When reading Haskell code for a function, I'd strongly recommend you start from its type. Knowing, for instance, the types of the arguments of `map` can greatly help understanding. Even if the type can be automatically inferred by the compiler, most programmers still make it explicit in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

f is a function that is a parameter of the map function since map has the following type:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

That it is, a function from a to b and a list of elements of type a and then using the function passed as the first parameter to convert the list (passed as second parameter) in a list of element of type b by using the function (passed as first parameter)

This function is very useful for traversing a list applying a function.

Let's say I have a list of numbers

For example:

```
[2,3,4,5]
```

If i want to add 1 to each element of the list I could use map as following:

```
map (+1) [2,3,4,5]
```

Or if you prefer the lambda use:

```
map (\x -> x+1) [2,3,4,5]
```

And we'll get as an answer:

```
[3,4,5,6]
```

So in the implementation of map

```
map f [] = []
map f (a:b) = f a:map f b
```

We can see that the f is this function that is used to transform the list by applying it to each element of the list

The implementation is recursive goes until the end of the list converting element by element and appending them to the list so the list has the same order as before the function was applied.

Answer (score 2):

In your `map` definition, `f` is the first argument you're supplying to it. Your first pattern match could also be defined with a lambda to denote *where* the parameter is coming from:

```
map f [] = -- ...
map \f -> \[] -> -- ...
```

In the second definition, you're recursing down the contents of the `(:)` pattern match:

```
map f (x:xs) = (f x) : (map f xs)
```

I'm applying `f` to the first element we see `x`, then *prepending* that result to the recursed call of `map` through the rest of `xs`.